# Encode a valid url into a valid pathname

Tags: javascript, node.js, url-encoding

I am a bit puzzled by this myself. If for some reasons I would like to encode any valid url into valid pathname, say, to be used on an image proxy with an url structure like:

```
http://image-proxy/hash_of_url/encoded_url
```

Is there an efficient way to achieve `encoded_url` in javascript? I am on node.js runtime.

I need to do this because it would be used by another proxy not in my control, which had problem with an url like this:

```
http://image-proxy/hash_of_url/?url=encoded_url
```

PS: `hash_of_url` is a hmac digest of original url, to ensure url is generated by server, but that's not important to my question.

Comment: You mean `encodeURIComponent`?

Comment: Is `encodeURIComponent` safe for pathname? I use it for my 2nd example for sure, but can we be sure `encodeURIComponent` encode the url to be a valid segment in pathname?

Comment: And `encodeURI` seem like a better fit than `encodeURIComponent` but my question remain, are they the best options?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to insert your encoded URL into a path you should use `encodeURIComponent` which will encode path boundary characters like `/`, `?`, `&` and so on.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeURI.asp